# Storing huge form submissions in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a form with over 50-100 form fields (conditional form), and need to save this in a MySQL database. I'm looking for an efficient way to store this data in a MySQL database. As far as I know I have two options, I'm looking for the best/most efficient way.

**Option 1**

Creating a `form_submissions` table with 100 columns, and insert it with one query.

**Option 2**

Creating a `key => value` table with four columns, for example these columns: `id, form_id, key, value`, where every form submission queries 50-100 times based on the amount of fields filled in.

---

Looking at above options, option 2 definitely feels better, as it would be way easier to save the formdata in the database, aswell not having an enormous table with (in my opinion) way too many columns.

Comment: Yeah, option #2 probably makes the most sense here. Plus it prevents you from having to change your table structure (and probably queries as well) once the requirement for a form with _101_ fields occurs for the first time ;-)

Comment: @04FS thats what I thought. However, won't doing that many queries (the form will be submitted around 50-100 times a day) screw things up in terms of performance?

Comment: 50-100 times a day is practically nothing

Comment: Are you sure you need 1 table with 100 fields? I suspect some datas may be refactored in relation tables and reduce the number of fields

Comment: See [this article](https://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/) which says "Normally our database server handles 1,000 inserts / sec. That wasn't enough. So I went looking for methods to improve the speed of MySQL inserts and was finally able to increase this number to 28,000 inserts per second."

Comment: @Cid yeah, there are no 'smart' methods to save some of these fields in relation tables. Almost all questions asked in the form are open questions where the value of the column will differ pretty much every submission.

Comment: @Quentin thank you :) I think i will go with option two then, looks way more comfortable!

Comment: That's a kind of survey ?

Comment: Yeah sort of @Cid

Comment: @Quentin benchmarks are pretty much relative and pretty much depend on MySQL server configuration and server hardware, but yes MySQL should not have trouble to handle 100 inserts a day,,

Comment: Also you could consider to use MySQL's [InnoDB's memcache plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-memcached.html) to store and query EVA or cosider the switch to MariaDB which has [Dynamic Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns-functions/) support for EVA models

Answer (score 2):

Your situation is not clear. The default way is one table per entity/form and one column per attribute/field (option 1). You should have very good reasons to use the EAV model (Option 2). But there is nothing like that in your question. "100 fields" isn't that much. Note that implementing a decent EAV design is not a simple task at all. You need to implement a "schema in schema", if you want to do it "right". And it's too easy to do it wrong. So "as it would be way easier to save the formdata in the database" - is a dream.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what could go wrong with EAV model? Because it doesnt seem that difficult to setup, two tables with 7 columns in total is basically the bare minimum for this to get it to work

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar Two tables means no meta data at all. You could as well save the data in a text file. What could go wrong, doing so?

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar try the following query on an EAV-Table: `SELECT * FROM fromdata WHERE field1 = 'x', and field2 = 'y' ORDER BY field3 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30`

Comment: Also the most common EAV models stores everthing as a string which means you lose precision when calculating with decimals, also you can't enforce data integrity and datatype, And which data the application need to correctly work you need to write more application code or database triggers to check all of this..  @ArkoElsenaar that is what Paul is most likely talking about.. *"what could go wrong with EAV model?"* The question should be what can go correct when using EAV design in a RDMS then we have less typing to do